# Google Assistant new users every 5-10 minutes

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm checking the logs of a chatbot I made for a client and I see something a bit strange.
I get new users on quite a regular basis, one every to 10 minutes (more or less)
And these user never go beyond the welcome intent.

It's as if a new person asked to talk with my assistant, got the welcome intent, then did absolutely nothing. Every time it's from a Google Home device (or anything with no screen capabilities).

It seems a bit odd to me, it's as if bots were checking if my assistant is still alive.
I can't find anything on google's documentation mentioning something like this.

Has anyone noted something similar?
Anyone could have an explanation to this ?

Best regards :)

Comment: oh snap, how could i miss that !
Thank you so much that perfectly answers my question !

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then

Comment: perfect, thank you i flagged it as valid answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google performs health checks on actions through out the day. The docs only state that they run throughout the day and don't mention a time period between checks, so I am not sure if these requests are just health checks, but you can identify health check requests by their *is_health_check* property. More on healthchecks can be found here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/health-checks